# CodecRegistryError: incompatible codecs in module "encodings.ascii" when running Nosetests in PyCharm

Tags: python, runtime-error, codec

I am attempting to run Nosetests through PyCharm using a virtual environment, and am running into the following error.

`encodings.CodecRegistryError: incompatible codecs in module "encodings.ascii" (/Users/Environments/work_dir/lib/python2.7/encodings/ascii.pyc)`

This is only happening in PyCharm, and running the nosetests through the terminal does not cause this issue.

I recently updated to Mac Version 10.14.1 (18B75). I think this may have something to do with the issue, as in the stack trace:

```
File "/Users/Environments/work_dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 184, in get_supported_platform
plat = 'macosx-%s-%s' % ('.'.join(_macosx_vers()[:2]), m.group(3))
```

Specifically refers to the Mac version.

How do I go about solving this issue?

Comment: I faced the same when I had site-packages enabled. Do you have them enabled as well?

Comment: @maddin25 I am not entirely sure how to check that, is that a PyCharm setting?

Comment: no, it should be a setting of your `virtualenv`. If you use `virtualenvwrapper`, then call `toggleglobalsitepackages`. Otherwise check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8887511/3702319

Answer (score 0):

Switched over to the Community Edition and the error no longer happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had special character in the project path. When removed "–" it started working.